# Gerrit sens timestamp via REST API with timezone

Tags: rest, gerrit

I tried to query our changes by Gerrit querybox. I need to add the timezone information and can get my result like this:

`after:"2020-05-08 22:30:55 +0400" before:"2020-05-08 22:40:33 +0400"`

The timezone setting `+0400` is required and the `"` is also required since the timezone information. Now I need use REST API to get the json result by following URL:

`http://GERRIT:8888/a/changes/?q=after:"2020-05-08 22:30:55 +0400" before:"2020-05-08 22:40:33 +0400"`

but I get an http `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`

Could someone help me check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes and to change the following characters:

```
space => +
+     => %2B
```

So, you need to change:

```
after:"2020-05-08 22:30:55 +0400" before:"2020-05-08 22:40:33 +0400"
```

To:

```
after:\"2020-05-08+22:30:55+%2B0400\"+before:\"2020-05-08+22:40:33+%2B0400\"
```

I was able to get the info executing:

```
curl -s --user USER:PASS --request GET "https://$GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/?q=after:\"2020-05-08+22:30:55+%2B0400\"+before:\"2020-05-08+22:40:33+%2B0400\""
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I tried your way to replace the `+` to `%2B` and the result is the same. Maybe the Gerrit REST API issue?
I also replace the ' ' -> `%20`, '"' -> `%22` and '+' -> `%2B` and the result is the same.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your info. I combined your method that `"` to `%22`, ` +` to `+%2B`, and ` ` to `%20`. Finally the REST API of Gerrit works.
Thanks

Comment: My final condition is: after:%222020-05-06%2023:19:00+%2B0400%22+before:%222020-05-07%2016:19:00+%2B0400%22